# selecting all row from two tables and one row from last table mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select all row from two tables and one row from last table mysql

My table is given below,

```
tbl_order

order_id    order_no
--------    --------
   1         1000
   2         1001
   3         1002

tbl_assign

assign_id    order_id    central_status
---------    --------    --------------
    1           1              1
    2           2              1
    3           3              1

tbl_unit_status

status_id    assign_id    status_status
---------    ---------    -------------
    1            1             Work
    2            2             Cutter
    3            2             Stitch
    4            1             Stitch
```

From the above 3 table, I want the result as,

```
order_id    order_no    assign_id    status_status
--------    --------    ---------    -------------
   3          1002          3           {null}
   2          1001          2           Stitch
   1          1000          1           Stitch
```

I have tried the below code,

`SELECT * FROM tbl_order o LEFT JOIN tbl_assign a ON a.order_id = o.order_id LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl_unit_status u ORDER BY u.status_id DESC LIMIT 1) uu ON uu.assign_id = a.assign_id WHERE a.central_status = 1 ORDER BY a.assign_id DESC`

But the result comes as,

```
order_id    order_no    assign_id    status_status
--------    --------    ---------    -------------
   3          1002          3           {null}
   2          1001          2           {null}
   1          1000          1           Stitch
```

Where am doing wrong. I have tried a lot. Please help me find the answer. Thank you.

Comment: A good effort, but see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
SELECT o.*,u2.assign_id,u2.status_status FROM tbl_order o 
LEFT JOIN tbl_assign a ON a.order_id = o.order_id LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT u.assign_id,max(u.status_id) as maxid FROM tbl_unit_status u  group by u.assign_id) 
uu ON uu.assign_id = a.assign_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_unit_status  u2 on u2.status_id = uu.maxid
 WHERE a.central_status = 1 ORDER BY a.assign_id DESC
```

Comment: now am getting 4 rows. I need only 3 rows where `order_id` should not repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_order o LEFT JOIN tbl_assign a ON a.order_id = o.order_id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl_unit_status u ORDER BY u.status_id DESC LIMIT 2) 
uu ON uu.assign_id = a.assign_id WHERE a.central_status = 1 ORDER BY 
a.assign_id DESC
```

With `LIMIT 1` you are only comparing with the last row from tbl_unit_status which has assign_id 1.

Comment: Cannot set limit as 2 because table rows will change dynamically.